# Enable snmp on linux

Tags: snmp

I have enable snmp on linux (Fedora) but i can access only to system group. Why?
Should I made changes in snmp.conf?

Thanks

Comment: I guess Fedora ships net-snmp as default. You may check that. Then Net-SNMP web site can be your guide. http://www.net-snmp.org/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to change the snmpd.conf file (note the **d** in snmp**d**.conf).  The default fedora configuration only allows you access to the system group.

Run "snmpconf -g basic_setup" to get you started, which will walk you through setting up the needed configuration file.

Or if you're in a hurry, put this in your snmpd.conf file to use insecure SNMPv2c to allow access to the whole agent:

```
  rocommunity PICKYOURCOMMUNITYNAME
```